# Android AWS Cognito app - User sign-in WITHOUT embedding sensitive info (like secret key)

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

**TL;DR** W/o distributed private keys, how can I perform the [auth flow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html?icmpid=docs_cognito_console#amazon-cognito-user-pools-admin-authentication-flow) for an Android app where the Identity Provider is Cognito itself, and the user only signs-up/in with email/password?

---

I'm developing an Android app in which I want the user to sign-in with "email and password" (NOT Google, Facebook, etc.) and then be able to download/upload objects from S3. I've worked with AWS for months, but all the while the sign-in functionality of my app was built on the sample app (the source of which has apparently changed substantially), which used the "AWSConfiguration" class to store:

- AWS_MOBILEHUB_USER_AGENT
- AMAZON_COGNITO_REGION
- AMAZON_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID
- AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID
- AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID
- AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_SECRET

**I need to implement sign-in and authorization to use AWS modules (like S3) WITHOUT embedding sensitive info.**

It seems clear to me that this is going to be a "roll my own" situation so in going back to the good ol' [start of the documentation on cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/cognito-auth.html), I'm already to confused as to why my "Email and password" sign-in model fits neither the bill of a ["Public Provider"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/external-identity-providers.html) nor a ["Developer Authenticated Identity"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html):

From Mobile Hub:
[image: "Email and password"]

In `Cognito > MyUserPool > App Integration > App client settings` it still appears as *an* identity provider of some kind (**also it worked without me having to "enable" it**):

[image: "Email and password" as an identity provider in User Pools]

**The big question:**
Is it possible to implement a sign-in flow where the user enters an email and a password, gets signed-in with Cognito, and the app has the necessary info to instantiate something like `S3Object = new S3Client(credentialsProvider).getObject(...)` without requiring a (separate/proxy) server to process private keys?

Also, are callback/sign-out URLs necessary for an app (and if so, why)?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question on the obfuscation of service constants in the SDK, there is no standard method to do this - which offers guaranteed security. There are several third party and server based solutions. However Cognito does not recommend any specific technique for obfuscation.

To implement Sign-In and get credentials to access AWS resources, you can add Cognito as a Authentication Provider for your identity-pool. With this you will be able to use ID token vended by Cognito to access AWS resources.  This code snippet shows how to use tokens issued by Cognito UserPools to access AWS resources in Android.

```
 // Get id token from CognitoUserSession.
    String idToken = cognitoUserSession.getIdToken().getJWTToken(); 

 // Create a credentials provider, or use the existing provider.
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(context, IDENTITY_POOL_ID, REGION);

 // Set up as a credentials provider.
    Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    logins.put("cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_123456789", cognitoUserSession.getIdToken().getJWTToken()); 
    credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
```

See this tutorial for further detail - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-android.html#tutorial-integrating-user-pools-getting-aws-credentials-android.